# Include an AAR library dependency in a Titanium Android module

Tags: android, ant, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I'm building an Android module with Titanium framework and I have to include an external dependency in AAR format. 
I've tried to extract only the classes JAR from the AAR (that is an archive) and to include it in the module, but that trick works only for libraries that not depends to any resources (that is the reason in making an AAR instead of a JAR).

Is there a way to include the AAR in the build process of the Titanium module (that uses Ant as build tool)?

**EDIT:**
seems that at Appcelerator someone will work on that: https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-18565

meanwhile, any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At present there is no direct way to include an AAR library dependency in a Titanium Android module. What you can do is extract only the classes JAR from the AAR and include the JAR. Include the resources extracted from the AAR in the project manually to corresponding directories.

Answer (score 0):

Titanium SDK 6.1.0 added native AAR support for both Java- and Hyperloop-based modules. Check-out the [Android Module Project](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Android_Module_Project) documentation for more infos.